# how to fix string arguments in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

"The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.",

```
Route<dynamic>  generateRoute(RouteSettings settings)  {
    switch (settings.name) {
        case HomeRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(HomeView(),settings.name);
        case AboutRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(AboutView(),settings.name);
        case SwishTokenRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(SwishToken(),settings.name);
        default: 
        throw "route not found!";
    }

}
```

Comment: please i need, If someone can help me make adjustment i would be happy

Answer (score 1):

On default you didnt put the return keyword that why its showing the error.

Comment: While that's a problem, what does it have to do with positional arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception if there is no match:

```dart
Route<dynamic>  generateRoute(RouteSettings settings)  {
           switch (settings.name) {
             case HomeRoute:
               return _getPageRoute(HomeView());
             case AboutRoute:
               return _getPageRoute(AboutView());
             case SwishTokenRoute:
               return _getPageRoute(SwishToken());
             default:
               throw "route not found!";
          }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot...i am still learning. i have issue with the positional arguments